# What is a 'rollback' in the context of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, badges

There is a badge ("Cleanup") awarded for first rollback. What do users do to gain this badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are able to perform edits, you can also perform a rollback, which is to revert one or more edits that has been made, much like revisions in Drupal.